# XMLSerializer.serializeToString and img data:uri has something wrong with comment node

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

```
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = '<!-- -- -->'
foreignObject.appendChild(div)
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
const img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg))}`
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

the `<!-- -- -->` makes the img load error，change to `<!-- a -->` is fine.
and the original comment node like this `<!--a id="TwitterLink" title="Share on Twitter"> <img id="TwitterImg" /></a> <a-- id="FacebookLink" title="Share on Facebook"> <img id="FacebookImg" /></a-->` here is a `<a--` inside the comment node

what cause this problem? please help

Comment: It's indeed surprising that `serializeToString()` has the *require well-formed* flag set to false and *can* produce invalid XML markup.

Answer (score 2):

You are in an XML document (SVG is a subset of XML), and even the foreign content must abide to the XML syntax. [In XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments), [contrarily to HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments), comments can't contain the sequence `--`.

Now, how come `XMLSerializer#serializeToString()`. doesn't produce a valid XML markup? No clue<sup>1</sup>, but [they indeed](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-xmlserializer-serializetostring) set the *require well-formed* flag to false, so you don't get any error [here](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-xml-serializing-a-comment-node).

You can still get the error earlier through the use of a `DOMParser`:

```js
const markup = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(new Comment(" -- "));
console.log({ markup });
const isInvalid = !!new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, "application/xml").querySelector("parsererror");
console.log({ isInvalid });
```

But this is just the first step for you.
Fixing that error isn't trivial, and maybe the best for you, since your goal is to display that SVG, would be to remove all the comment nodes from the input DOM:

```js
function removeComments(input) {
  const tree = input.cloneNode(true);
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(tree);
  while(walker.nextNode()) {
    if (walker.currentNode.nodeType === 8) {
      walker.currentNode.remove();
    }
  }
  return tree;
}
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
const foreignObject = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = '<!-- -- -->'
foreignObject.appendChild(div)
svg.appendChild(foreignObject);
const img = document.createElement('img')
img.src = `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(removeComments(svg)))}`
document.body.appendChild(img)
img.onload = (evt) => console.log("loaded fine");
```

But other XML errors could still be present, so you might need the first test, and another fix for these.

<sup>1. I dug [this issue](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=25168) up from the archives, where it's explained they went with the already non-throwing behavior, when they specced it, but left the option of adding a flag to `serializeToString()` for a future iteration, which has yet to come. I guess you could try to make your case heard at https://github.com/w3c/DOM-Parsing/issues. A former request was done in the [W3C mailing list](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2014AprJun/0271.html), but it didn't get any response.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTML 5 specification, `--` is not permitted inside a comment

> Comments must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN
> SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D
> HYPHEN-MINUS (<!--). Following this sequence, the comment may have
> text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start
> with a single U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN ('>') character, nor start with
> a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (-) character followed by a U+003E GREATER-THAN
> SIGN ('>') character, **nor contain two consecutive U+002D
> HYPHEN-MINUS (-) characters**, nor end with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (-)
> character. Finally, the comment must be ended by the three character
> sequence U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+003E GREATER-THAN
> SIGN (-->).

[https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/syntax.html#comments:~:text=nor%20contain%20two%20consecutive%20U%2B002D%20HYPHEN%2DMINUS%20(%2D)%20characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/syntax.html#comments:%7E:text=nor%20contain%20two%20consecutive%20U%2B002D%20HYPHEN%2DMINUS%20(%2D)%20characters)

Comment: This document is way out-dated.  The current specs are https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments (or https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#comment-state if you wish the state machine) and there `<!-- -- -->` is parsed just well. The thing is, OP isn't in an HTML document, but in an SVG one.

Comment: This is the link you want to cite: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments Now the question is how come `XMLSerializer` produces incorrect XML data...